# How to use ngFor with a an array of an object array : angular 5

Tags: angular

I have this class structure:

```
 export class CarsData {
     public PrimaryCars: string[];
     public SecondaryCars: string[];

 }

 export class Cars {
     public CarsInfo: Array<CarsData>;
 }
```

How do I ngFor into CarsInfo ? 
I did as follows:

```
*ngFor="let car of CarsInfo"
   {{car.PrimaryCars}}
   {{car.SecondaryCars}}
```

Comment: post your JSON data

Answer (score 3):

Based on your data you don't have nested arrays, its just an object with two arrays inside,
so you need,

```
<div *ngFor="let car of CarsInfo">
    <div *ngFor="let primary of car.PrimaryCars">{{ primary }}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let secondary of car.SecondaryCars">{{ secondary  }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div *ngFor="let car of CarsInfo">
    <div *ngFor="let p of car.PrimaryCars">{{ p }}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let s of car.SecondaryCars">{{ s }}</div>
</div>
```